# javascript making a jquery countdown work with UTC times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this jquery countdown:

https://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

I initialize it like this:

```
        <div id="clock"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#clock').countdown('2015/03/27 00:00:00')
              .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
                var format = '%H:%M:%S';
                if(event.offset.days > 0) {
                  format = '%-D day%!d ' + format;
                }
                $(this).html(event.strftime(format));
               })
             .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
               $(this).html('FINISHED!');
             });
        </script>
```

The target time I use is in UTC but it will only work if people enter the site in UTC. I need to make it work in all the timezones, I mean, wherever the user is from it always has to see the same time left...

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var finalDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 03, 27))

$('#clock').countdown(finalDate)
    .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
    ...
```

This way the finalDate variable will contain the '2015/03/27 00:00:00' date *in the client's timezone*.

Note that the [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) function also takes optional hour, minute, second, and millisecond parameters in case you want to specify those as well for your countdown.

Comment: mmmm it is giving me strange values in the countdown..if i use --> var finalDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2015,03,11)); then the countdown is 40days and some hours and should be 11 days aprox..

Comment: and if i use --> var finalDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2015,03,27)); I am only seeing the hours in the countdown!!

Comment: @Egidi javascript months are 0-based so 3 corresponds to April. But when you create the date with the string constructor it adjusts this for you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the library uses local clock on the client. So you have to change the countdown date depending on the timezone.

I can't find anything about the timezone in the documentation : 
http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html

Maybe you can use a function like this on the date :

```
d.setHours(d.getHours() - parseInt(-d.getTimezoneOffset() / 60));
```